# Calculated distance field along GPX track

Tags: qgis, distance, gpx

I have dropped a GPS breadcrumb track (.gpx format) onto my project.  If I generate a a virtual field in this layer to calculate the distance between successive crumbs using the expression:

```
distance(($geometry),geometry(get_feature_by_id( @layer_name, $id+1)))
```

I get totally misleading results.  Why is this?  And is there anyway around it without saving the GPX file as a projected shapefile and redoing the calculation (which then works fine)?

Comment: What is misleading about the results?

Comment: they are blatantly incorrect - points that are far from the next point do not necessarily have greater values than points that are close.  The values calculated are decimal (0.02-0.07) whereas the actual distance between pairs ranges from 1 to about 1200m

Answer (score 5):

The small values are likely because the CRS of GPX files is WGS84 (measured in degrees, not meters). In which case you will need to transform the points to a projected coordinate system.

Something like:

```
distance(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:32735'), transform(geometry(get_feature_by_id( @layer_name, $id+1)), 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:32735'))
```

Although this may be slow, depending how many points you have.

---

The problem with the calculated distances not corresponding with what you see on the map is that the points might not be ordered 1 to 1 with `$id` and `timestamp`. It is hard to tell without seeing your data.

Comment: The transformation resulted in values now in the range of 10-9500 (ie now too big!) and still bearing no correspondence with actual spacing (ie large spacing does not necessarily have large values).

Comment: I made a calculated field to show $id and this is correct - 1st record has $id 1, second $id 2 etc

Comment: The fact that it all works when saved as a shapefile makes me think that you are in the right track and its to do with transformation and CRS.  The CRS of my project is EPSG:32737

Comment: The expression is now as follows, but I still get misleading results:   distance(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:32737'), transform (geometry(get_feature_by_id( @layer_name, $id+1)), 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:32737'))